# Mail::IMAPClient->new hangs in Windows

Tags: windows, perl, imap

This `Mail::IMAPClient->new()` freezes in Windows 7:

```
sub connectGMail
{
    my $client = Mail::IMAPClient->new
    (
        Server   => 'imap.gmail.com',
        Port     => 993,
        Ssl      =>  1,
        User     => 'whateverUser',
        Password => 'aG00dP455w0rd',
        Socket   => IO::Socket::SSL->new
        (       
            SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE
        )
    )
    or die "Cannot connect  ($@)\n";
    return $client;
}
```

I tried deactivating Windows firewall, but nothing changed.

A very similar code works fine in Linux:

```
sub connectGMail
{
    my $client = Mail::IMAPClient->new
    (
        Server   => 'imap.gmail.com',
        Port     => 993,
        Ssl      =>  1,
        User     => 'whateverUser',
        Password => 'aG00dP455w0rd'
    )
    or die "Cannot connect  ($@)\n";
    return $client;
}
```

In both cases `Mail::IMAPClient` was installed fine from CPAN repositories, but in Windows, if I don't include the *Socket* option, it shows me this warning

```
*******************************************************************
 Using the default of SSL_verify_mode of SSL_VERIFY_NONE for client
 is deprecated! Please set SSL_verify_mode to SSL_VERIFY_PEER
 together with SSL_ca_file|SSL_ca_path for verification.
 If you really don't want to verify the certificate and keep the
 connection open to Man-In-The-Middle attacks please set
 SSL_verify_mode explicitly to SSL_VERIFY_NONE in your application.
*******************************************************************
```

and the rest of the script (which parses the emails) won't work correctly.

```
error:    unexpected end of header


error:    unexpected end of header


error:    unexpected end of header
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `Mail::IMAPClient->new` doesn't like both a socket and the server/port. If I create the socket with server/port then pass it, it does connect successfully.

```
sub connectGMail
{
    my $socket = IO::Socket::SSL->new
    (  
       PeerAddr => 'imap.gmail.com',  
       PeerPort => 993, 
       SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE
    )  
    or die "socket(): $@";  

    my $client = Mail::IMAPClient->new
    (
        User     => 'whateverUser',
        Password => 'aG00dP455w0rd'
        Socket   => $socket
    )
    or die "Cannot connect  ($@)\n";
    return $client;
}
```

Comment: If you read [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Mail::IMAPClient#Socket), you'll see that if you supply the socket, "then you are responsible for establishing the connection, i.e. make sure that `$ssl` in the example is a valid and connected socket."

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've read the documentation in fact, but skipped that part since I didn't use Socket the first time...